# what is the best way to refresh the network stack in android?

Tags: android, networking

After a long period of inactivity within my app, all the get requests start failing with a connection timeout error. I notice this was happening when the phone is connected over the 3G network, and not when it is connected to wifi..
At present to get it to work, i toggle the airplane mode state twice and the network connections get reset.Is this the best way to go about doing this ? Please enlighten!

```
void toggleAirplaneMode(){

    //Toggling airplane mode to restart network
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(
              context.getContentResolver(), 
              Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;

        // toggle airplane mode
        Settings.System.putInt(
              context.getContentResolver(),
              Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

        // Post an intent to reload
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        Log.d("Inetify", "Toggling Airplane Mode");
}
```

Comment: Facing something similar.